# Boost python object lifetime

Tags: c++, python, boost, garbage-collection

cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;

struct Foo
{
   virtual ~Foo() {}
   virtual void Print() = 0;
};

struct FooWrap : Foo, wrapper<Foo>
{
    void Print()
    {
        this->get_override("Print")();
    }
};

void ProcessFoo(Foo *obj) { obj->Print(); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    class_<FooWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
        .def("Print", pure_virtual(&Foo::Print));
    def("ProcessFoo", &ProcessFoo);
}
```

python:

```
import hello_ext

class NewFoo(hello_ext.Foo):
   def Print(self):
      print 'Print call'

hello_ext.ProcessFoo( NewFoo() )
```

Everything works fine, there is `Print call` text from `ProcessFoo` call. But I want to store all passed pointers to `ProcessFoo` like:

```
std::vector<Foo*> data;
void ProcessFoo(Foo *obj) { data.push_back(obj); obj->Print(); }
```

After exit from function pointer becomes invalid and I can't use it from vector. What are the best way to make lifetime of that pointer bigger? Use shared pointers or tell python not to delete object (if it deletes it?)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store this pointer, you have to increment the reference count of ther underlying python object (PyObject). For this you have to implement your void ProcessFoo(Foo *obj) to get a python object instead of the C++ object, because otherwise boost::python will strip of the python object for you in his adaptionand you cannot control its lifetime anymore.

If you do this, you also have to do the conversion to you C++ type explicitely (but with boost::python this is not so much trouble).

```
using namespace boost::python;
std::vector< std::pair<object, Foo&> > myVec;

void ProcessFoo(object o )
{
  Foo& x = extract<Foo&>(o);
  // ... do you add to container here, but remember, to add the object o
  // too, otherwise the refernce counter will be decremented and the object
  // may go away.
  myVec.push_back( std::make_pair( o, x ) );
}
```

Comment: can you have `Foo&` in `std::pair` ?

Comment: Yes you can have. It is nothing more than a "pointer". But you have to ensure the object is not accessed after deletion which is ensured by incrementing and storing the reference (object).